# Is ML and DL turning math into code? beginner

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, artificial-intelligence

I've gathered some interest over artificial intelligence (ml and dl) and noticed a lot of it is turning math into code if you wish to improve upon a model that will make a prediction.

If you wanted to improve a model does it require you to create and think of math equation that will make accurate prediction and turn it into code (essentially just giving a computer complex math problem to solve) ?

---

For example take python django framework for building web applications, if you wanted to learn to build web app you don't have to build framework from scratch or know networking protocols and everything in detail where everything is routed, but having good understanding of how to deliver the data to user with django will give you ability to build amazing web applications.

Is ml and dp just not there yet? where we have set of "rules" to predict a certain outcome? a lot of ml and dl seem like they need improvement and many companies are not sharing the code because it's new and has a lot of potential.

Thinking about diving deep into math and equations seems hard and then writing them and turning them into code seems like it will take years to master. Would there in the future be a programming language or framework where we can learn set of tools to make certain outcome without knowing what's behind it? It feels like we are going lower than 0 and 1 with current state of ml and dl.

Is it worth to dive deep into current ml and dl tools and learn them? While others create those tools with math?

Those are some of my concers with getting into ml and dl if anyone can answer a part of it. It would help a lot. **Thank you**

Comment: Actually, you can easily implement basic machine learning concepts, one of the arguably most basic ones being linear regression, in programming languages without knowing the formulas. The same holds for loads of other concepts. If that is advisable, though, is another question, which I, and probably many other people in this particular forum, would strongly negate.

Answer (score 0):

Broadly speaking, you are correct that in machine learning we are given some data $\mathbf{X}$ and labels $y$ and we want to learn some function $f$, such that

$$
y = f(\mathbf{X}) + \varepsilon
$$

where $\varepsilon$ is some noise. More formally, this is an oversimplification, as noise does not have to be additive, and the structure of noise may be mroe complicated, though the take away message is that the function $f$ is noisy. So yes, $f$ is a mathematical function. For simple functions (decision tree, $k$-NN, naive Bayes, linear regression) and small datasets you could solve the machine learning problems by pen and paper. For real life problems, this would be at best time demanding, if not impossible, so we use computers to help us. So machine learning does not have to be about "turning math into code", though it usually is.

Machine learning usually *does not* "require you to create and think of math equation that will make accurate prediction and turn it into code". It is true, that in some cases we want to describe problems with custom mathematical functions, and use optimization algorithms to fit those functions to the data, though I'd say that this is usually realm of statistics rather than machine learning. In machine learning you usually choose among available models (naive Bayes, random forest, XGBoost, $k$-NN, SVM, etc), or among deep learning architectures (feed forward, RNN, Transformer, CNN, etc), where you usually need to make some adjustments to the models (hyperparameter tuning, changes in the architecture), since out-of-the-box they do not need to give you perfect fit to the data. Those models *are* the "building blocks", similar to the "building blocks" you can use for web development in popular frameworks. There also *are* some frameworks you can use, e.g. [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/), [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/), or [Keras](https://keras.io/), but same as with web development frameworks, you need to learn to use them first.

> Would there in the future be a programming language or framework where
> we can learn set of tools to make certain outcome without knowing
> what's behind it?

This is a rather philosophical question. You seem to be referring to something known as automated machine learning (AutoML), where the algorithms would "learn by themselves" without needing human supervision. It's hard to say if we'd ever achieve this, as machine learning problems usually require a lot of human expertise to done correctly. Another problem is that in machine learning we often see *garbage in, garbage out* issues, where bad data leads to poor results. In many cases machine learning algorithm *by itself* won't know that the results are bad, as this would need it to understand the world and have knowledge about the world, i.e. we would be talking rather about general artificial intelligence. Using web design analogy again, the available web design frameworks do not as well solve problems themselves, you need human developers that know how to use them to create a web page. You can check the open access [*Automated Machine Learning*](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-05318-5) book by Hutter, Kotthoff, and Vanschoren for more detail.

Finally, let me try to answer the general question I read between the lines. You seem to be asking if one needs to dive deep into mathematics to use machine learning. For doing basic stuff, you don't have to. You can simply pick some out-of-the-box model from scikit-learn and apply it to your data, same as you could use WordPress and some free layout to setup online blog in few clicks. On another hand, for many problems the simple solutions would be not enough.